# rosnode name of connected publishers (rospy)

Tags: ros, rospy, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a rospy Subscriber which is connected to several publishers, and I would like to retrieve a list of the names of the rosnodes that are connected as publishers to that subscriber, via a rospy interface.  I have looked at the Subscriber.impl API and I thought that maybe it was in *impl.connections* or *impl.get_stats*, but *connections* gives you the address (I think) of the connected nodes... something like

```
[<rospy.impl.tcpros_base.TCPROSTransport object at 0x17e3450>, ...]
```

Thanks for the help!

Cheers,
Kel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66049/rosnode-name-of-connected-publishers-(rospy)/) by [Kel Guerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3982/kel-guerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're going for, but you can check where each message came from:

```
def callback(data):
    print data._connection_header['callerid']
```

For more information, see Section 2.1 [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers).

Edit:

This information is available if you're willing to interact directly with the rosmaster. I sure hope somebody comes along with a better way to do this! (Building on the example [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Master_API)):

```
import os
import xmlrpclib
caller_id = '/script'
m = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(os.environ['ROS_MASTER_URI'])
code, msg, val = m.getSystemState(caller_id)
topic = '/chatter'
if code == 1:
    pubs, subs, srvs = val
    pub_names = [elem[1] for elem in pubs if elem[0] == topic]
```

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kel Guerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3982/kel-guerin/) on 2013-06-27**:
Thank you so much, I will try this out!!